# Can't compile cxxtest generated cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, cxxtest

So I have a visual studio 2015 c++ project with a testsuite.h file like the one in the cxx documentation. I run the cxxtestgen python tool to generate a testsuite.cpp. I put the testsuite.cpp file in another visual studio 2015 c++ empty project. Add cxxtest to the additional include directories of the project. 
But when I build i get the following error:

```
cannot open include file: cxxtest/TestListener.h
```

But it is there in the additional include directory folder.

Comment: Did you try to `#include <TestListener.h>` without the `cxxtest/`?

Comment: ah yes, that fixed it.